# Strange artifacts on graphics saved as PDF

Tags: plotting, pdf-format

I have a problem when plotting 3D graphs. Plotting any graph with the default settings using `Plot3D`, e.g.

```
Plot3D[Sin[Pi*x]*Sin[2 Pi*y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

produces graphs with correct labels, but trying to save them as PDF using the right click menu makes the label text messed up:

[image: Broken labels]

Note that the problem is only affecting saving using the Mathematica menu (the choice of options does not seem to matter) and only saving to PDF (other formats are okay). I am able to export PDFs without any issues using `Export`.

Does anyone know where the problem comes from? I was able to save very similar plots before with no problem, and I haven't changed anything since then.

I am using Mathematica 10.0.0 on Linux. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: It's a known issue I think. It's mentioned here somewhere that one should not save a Graphics through the menu until WRI fixes this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on MMA 10.3.1 on Win7-64 bit. This is a [screen capture of the PDF](http://i.imgur.com/jz2uHP7.gif) generated from right-click saving the graphic. I would conclude that the problem has since been fixed by Wolfram, hopefully for Linux as well as for Windows.